# Can't use copy&paste while using VMWare unity

Tags: windows, vmware, ubuntu-unity

I'd like to use vmware unity function, which all screens in same place,so I don't need to switch between vmware and windows. But when using unity, I can't copy text from the original windows window to a unity window. I have installed vmware tool. I can copy text or file between vmware and windows without using unity.
My environment:
windows7, vwmare workstation 8, windows server 2008 x64(inside vmware)

Please help.

Comment: This is a bug in vmware it seems - discussion here (with unreliable workaround): http://communities.vmware.com/thread/335106?start=15&tstart=0